# How to get media by Location Id

Tags: c#, instagram, instagram-api, visual-studio-2019, instasharp

Im using the private api InstaSharper, c#

I got all the media using tags without problems, however when i try to get media by location id, the result returns Null.

```
IResult<InstaLocationFeed> LocationSharch= await api.GetLocationFeed(2593354, PaginationParameters.MaxPagesToLoad(3));

List<InstaMedia> LocationList = LocationSharch.Value.Medias.ToList();
```

i want to get all the last media uploaded in a country location
example Spain.

Comment: well how do you know that is a valid location?

Comment: I read that is in the url of a search Example: https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/6889842/paris-france/ , So the id is 6889842

Comment: I don´t know how to get it with name, because the method request a id that is a Long and the Max pages parameter.